# javaFXでTreeTableColumnのChoiceBoxを動的にできない

Tags: java, javafx

```
TreeTableColumn<XxxInstance, String> mColumn;
// ①マッピング
mColumn.setCellValueFactory(new TreeItemPropertyValueFactory<>("xxx"));
// ②ChoiceBoxで表示
mColumn.setCellFactory(ChoiceBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(xxx));
```

②でCELLごとにChoiceBoxの選択項目を変えたいのですが、可能でしょうか？
ChoiceBoxの設定はsetCellFactoryしか用意されてないのでしょうか？
Callbackを実装してみました、CELL側にも設定メソッドが見つかりませんでした

Answer (score 0):

自己解決しました。Callbackの実装でChoiceBoxをsetGraphic()でCELL毎に設定できました。